# Use JQuery to check if element has a border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, border

So I'm playing with `$(el).css()`, trying to determine if an element has a border. I use `.css("border-style", "solid")` to set the border, which works, but actually it sets 4 individual styles:

```
border-right-style
border-left-style
border-top-style
border-bottom-style
```

So, checking for a border is a bit cumbersome as you have to do something like:

```
if ($(el).css("border-right-style") == "solid" && $(el).css("border-left-style") == "solid" && ...) {}
```

Simply checking for `$(el).css("border-style") != ""` doesn't works since `border-style` is always equal to "".

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: why you don't work with classes?

Comment: I usually do but in this particular case, the styles are so dynamic and so specific to each element that it's easier to do it this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`border-style` is Shorthand and you cant get them together so you have to get them separatly, because As per [Jquery CSS documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported.
For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, 
use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know if 4 properties are ALL set, then yes you have to check 4 properties. Although I would cache the selector.

```
$el = $('a');
if ($el.css("border-right-style") == "solid" && $el.css("border-left-style") == "solid" && $el.css("border-top-style") == "solid" && $el.css("border-bottom-style") == "solid") 
{
    alert('yay');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HLrJA/5/)

Comment: So a question I have is, does "border-style" even truly exist in CSS? Or is it just a shortcut for the other 4?

Comment: The latter, border-style sets 4 properties. If you inspect using a debugger tool there is usually a "computed styles" options which will show them all. The single line border: 1 px solid blue sets 12 properties.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to do what you are trying. The DOM only provides the styles for the element that were assigned inline or to the element in script. It doesn't show if it inherited a style such as a border from CSS declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to test the properties but this can make it a little more abstract...

```
function check(sel, prop) {
    var i, property, $o = $(sel), directions = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"];

    for (i = 0; i < directions.length; i++) {
        property = $o.css(prop + '-' + directions[i] + '-style');
        if (property !== 'solid') {
             return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I thought about something like this but imo it's harder to read.

Comment: With little change you can make it a jQuery plugin and abstract the property name so that you can reuse it to test other shorthand property values. You decrease the method's readability but increase overall readability (`$('p').checkProperty('margin', '5px')`).

Answer (score 0):

It can display the style values from inherited CSS files....

alert($("selector").css("border-bottom-color"));