# jQuery .css('border') Returns Nothing in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I'm working on a page with textareas. Some of these textareas have a class called "whitebord" which looks like this:

```
textarea.whitebord, textarea.whitebord:focus {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}
```

I also have a jQuery script that sets the border to 1px solid black. My script first checks to see if a border exists, if it does then it leaves it alone, however if there is no border it defaults to black. I check to see if a border exists using this:

```
$(this).css('border')
```

This works great in chrome and ie, however in Firefox it returns nothing, despite the fact that I know it has a border. Is this a known bug or what?

If you guys need any additional information just ask,

Comment: please share the code with us or just make the fiddle

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226073/getting-css-border-value-with-jquery-in-firefox-14-0-1

Comment: @Chris: That was it :)

Comment: Be careful with this if you use these values for calculations! Try getting the border width when the browser is zoomed. it will return a value you don't expect. http://jsfiddle.net/w1ll3m/JPkEq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this before - I needed to check all the borders (left, right, top, bottom) individually.

```
$el = $('a');
if ($el.css("border-right-style") == "solid" && $el.css("border-left-style") == "solid" && $el.css("border-top-style") == "solid" && $el.css("border-bottom-style") == "solid") 
{
    alert('yay');
}
```

From: [Use JQuery to check if element has a border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899789/use-jquery-to-check-if-element-has-a-border)